# Read host process packet size

Tags: python, psutil

I want to know the number of packets and the packet size for each packet sent by every process in the host computer.
I have tried using psutil the library:

```
         p=psutil.Process(pid)
         process_connection=p.connections()
```

But it shows the address and port but no information about the packet.

```
         psutil.net_io_counters()
```

This shows the bytes sent and received by the host.

How can I get this information using Python 2.7 and Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you need to apply a packet sniffer for that. The process statistics do not collect (meta-)information about each and every packet sent by a process, that would be very inefficient with respect to both processing power and memory footprint.

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is one of the popular packages providing packet sniffing from Python for unixes, but I don’t know about its support for windows or other packages which support windows.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try steel script to do packet sniffing